# Convert Pickle Object into JS-readable Code?

Tags: javascript, pickle

I'm pretty new to the Pickle Library and JS. I am writing code in JS to interact with a Python server; when I make a POST to the Python server, I am returned a pickled float. I want to convert the float into a JS-readable object.

The server returns something like `pickle.dumps(3.14159,0)`. When I print this value in Python, I get `b'F3.14159\n.'` However, the library I'm working with, JPickle, cannot interpret the 'b' in the return (or at least, that's what I'm guessing...when I try to unpickle my response using `console.log(jpickle.loads(response))`, I get a "unhandled opcode" error). Separate from the POST request, `jpickle.loads('F3.14159\n.')` gives me 3.14159, but `jpickle.loads(b'F3.14159\n.')` fails to compile. I'm not sure how to change the response I get from the POST because it is unreadable in JS, so I'm unsure how to go about solving this problem.

I'm open to any solutions that don't involve changing the server-side code (I don't have control over it), including using another library. I've tried JsonPickle with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Use just JSON, no pickle library required; Python comes with the `json` module and browser JS can, out of the box, parse json into values.

Serialize your data via something like `json.dump` and use `JSON.parse` in the browser to deserialize it.

Comment: Thanks for your response! But I was wondering if there is a JS solution as I don't have control over the server side code.

Answer (score 1):

A little late, but the answers in attached might help:: the code allows Javascript on a browser to traverse and decode compressed pickled objects coming from Python via Ajax.

[Is there an already published Javascript solution to traverse Python pickled objects without using Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71797909/is-there-an-already-published-javascript-solution-to-traverse-python-pickled-obj)

Make sure that the mime type is allowing you to pass binary numbers.

Comment: Hi! @Tunneller I'm also interested in parsing some picked object string from a javascript program. Is you solution able to parse level 2 pickle? and is your somewhat solution consolidated in a github repo somewhere? Or is it just the stuff you posted in three parts on that post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71797909/is-there-an-already-published-javascript-solution-to-traverse-python-pickled-obj  Thanks for clarifying! :)

Comment: Hi, sorry, I didn't ever upload to Github. https://github.com/jlaine/node-jpickle says that it supports pickle protocol level 3.  It works really well. My users interface is a lot faster than when I used JSON. I pickle then compress then send to javascript then uncompress and then unpickle.

Comment: Hi Fil, were you able to get this to work?

Comment: Yes! I did it! check out my project on github called 'LeoJS' . I convert pickled back and from without trouble up to level 2. (which is what I needed) I've annotated my code with tips to help doing so. Feel free to ask on github also for some help. (I'm boltex on github by the way)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I use it on my dashboard. When a certain button is clicked a loading animation is launched while a small json dictionary "data" is created and sent over to the url '/dashboard/command' waiting over on the Python side (Flask). Python answers the questions in "data" then replies with a binary blob. I had trouble on the Flask side enforcing the mimeType so here I cheat and just tell javascript that it is a blob no matter what the mimeType says.

```
        const jqXHR = $.ajax({             // result is a Promise
            url:  '/dashboard/command',
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            xhr: function() {
               var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
               xhr.overrideMimeType('application/octet-stream; charset=x-user-defined');
               xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                  if (xhr.readyState == 2) {                 //HEADERS_RECEIVED = 2, time to update the responseType
                     if (xhr.status == 200) {
                        xhr.responseType = "blob";
                    } else {
                        xhr.responseType = "text";
                    }
                  }
                  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {                 //DONE = 4, what did we get?
                      if (xhr.status == 200) {
                        console.log(xhr.response instanceof Blob); // should be a blob
                    } else if (xhr.responseText != "") {
                        console.log(xhr.responseText);
                        alert(xhr.responseText);
                  }
               }
             };
            return xhr;
           }
          });

          jqXHR.done( function(data_msg) {
              console.log("Blob Received")
              $("#update-plot").prop('disabled', false);  // Re-enable button
              $("#update-plot-loading").addClass('invisible');  // Hide loading animation
              let blob = data_msg
              let reader = new FileReader();
              reader.onload = function(e) {              // binary data 
                  var blobdata = e.target.result
                  $("#update-plot").trigger('update', [blobdata, blobdata.byteLength]);   //will read the data and make plot, etc
              };
              reader.onerror = function(e) {             // error occurred
                  console.log('OnError : ' + e.type); 
              };
              reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);          // creates a readme promise based on the Ajax promise
          });

          jqXHR.fail( function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
              console.log("OnFail Textstatus:"+textStatus)
              target[0].prop('disabled', false);  // Re-enable button
              target[1].addClass('invisible');  // Hide loading spinner
              return(jqXHR.responseText)
          });
```

The code for everything else was on that previous answer, except for one small detail. To get from the compressed zlib binary I use Pako and it creates charcode not string, so I needed to unpack.

```
       const x = pako.inflate(binary_array)                      //  here goes

//       y = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(x)) - causes a stack overflow??!
// so we do it as a loop

       let x_str = []
       for (let i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
           x_str[i] = String.fromCharCode(x[i])
       }
       const updated_msg = x_str.join('');
```

Hope this helps.